# Extract the last line from all text files by recursively searching from a specific directory

Tags: linux, bash

The question may seem duplicate but I couldn't find any solution to this problem on StackOverflow. I am looking for a `one line` Linux command that can extract the last line of all text files recursively searching from a specific directory.

I can get the last line of all files from a specific directory (`tail -n1 *.txt`) and separately get a list of all text files by recursive using the `find` command. But I am unable to combine them to achieve my goal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ... `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec tail -n1 {} \;`

Comment: in addition to the `-exec` option in `find`, piping output into `xargs` is very powerful; e.g., if the only way to get a list of files were from the output of `grep` or something, `xargs` can do what `-exec` can do as part of `find`;  just mentioning it for future reference if/when you face a similar task but `find` cannot produce the list of files you want to work with;  HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -name \*.txt -exec tail -1 {} \;`